# Comparing Conv2D with padding between Tensorflow and PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to import weights saved from a Tensorflow model to PyTorch. So far the results have been very similar. I ran into a snag when the model calls for `conv2d` with `stride=2`.

To verify the mismatch, I set up a very simple comparison between TF and PyTorch. First, I compare `conv2d` with `stride=1`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


np.random.seed(0)
sess = tf.Session()

# Create random weights and input
weights = torch.empty(3, 3, 3, 8)
torch.nn.init.constant_(weights, 5e-2)
x = np.random.randn(1, 3, 10, 10)

weights_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(weights.numpy(), dtype=tf.float32)
# PyTorch adopts [outputC, inputC, kH, kW]
weights_torch = torch.Tensor(weights.permute((3, 2, 0, 1)))

# Tensorflow defaults to NHWC
x_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x.transpose((0, 2, 3, 1)), dtype=tf.float32)
x_torch = torch.Tensor(x)

# TF Conv2D
tf_conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(x_tf,
                         weights_tf,
                         strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                         padding="SAME")

# PyTorch Conv2D
torch_conv2d = F.conv2d(x_torch, weights_torch, padding=1, stride=1)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tf_result = sess.run(tf_conv2d)

diff = np.mean(np.abs(tf_result.transpose((0, 3, 1, 2)) - torch_conv2d.detach().numpy()))
print('Mean of Abs Diff: {0}'.format(diff))
```

The result of this execution is:

```
Mean of Abs Diff: 2.0443112092038973e-08
```

When I change `stride` to 2, the results start to vary.

```
# TF Conv2D
tf_conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(x_tf,
                         weights_tf,
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                         padding="SAME")

# PyTorch Conv2D
torch_conv2d = F.conv2d(x_torch, weights_torch, padding=1, stride=2)
```

The result of this execution is:

```
Mean of Abs Diff: 0.2104552686214447
```

According to PyTorch documentation, [`conv2d` uses zero-padding](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) defined by the `padding` argument. Thus, zeros are added to the left, top, right, and bottom of the input in my example.

If PyTorch simply adds padding on both sides based on the input parameter, it should be easy to replicate in Tensorflow.

```
# Manually add padding - consistent with PyTorch
paddings = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]])
x_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x.transpose((0, 2, 3, 1)), dtype=tf.float32)
x_tf = tf.pad(x_tf, paddings, "CONSTANT")

# TF Conv2D
tf_conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(x_tf,
                         weights_tf,
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                         padding="VALID")
```

The result of this comparison is:

```
Mean of Abs Diff: 1.6035047067930464e-08
```

What this tells me is that if I am somehow able to replicate the default padding behavior from Tensorflow into PyTorch, then my results will be similar.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853243/tensorflow-conv2d-diffrent-start-index-between-even-and-odd-stride?noredirect=1&lq=1) inspected the behavior of padding in Tensorflow. [TF documentation explains how padding is added for "SAME" convolutions.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Notes_on_SAME_Convolution_Padding) I discovered these links while writing this question.

Now that I know the padding strategy of Tensorflow, I can implement it in PyTorch.

Comment: tensorflow `SAME` padding may pad more pixels on the right than left. So in case of 10x10 image with 3x3 kernel and stride of 2, tensorflow will only pad one column in the right and bottom, which is different from torch padding=1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To replicate the behavior, padding sizes are calculated as described in the Tensorflow documentation. Here, I test the padding behavior by setting `stride=2` and padding the PyTorch input.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


np.random.seed(0)
sess = tf.Session()

# Create random weights and input
weights = torch.empty(3, 3, 3, 8)
torch.nn.init.constant_(weights, 5e-2)
x = np.random.randn(1, 3, 10, 10)

weights_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(weights.numpy(), dtype=tf.float32)
weights_torch = torch.Tensor(weights.permute((3, 2, 0, 1)))

# Tensorflow padding behavior. Assuming that kH == kW to keep this simple.
stride = 2
if x.shape[2] % stride == 0:
    pad = max(weights.shape[0] - stride, 0)
else:
    pad = max(weights.shape[0] - (x.shape[2] % stride), 0)

if pad % 2 == 0:
    pad_val = pad // 2
    padding = (pad_val, pad_val, pad_val, pad_val)
else:
    pad_val_start = pad // 2
    pad_val_end = pad - pad_val_start
    padding = (pad_val_start, pad_val_end, pad_val_start, pad_val_end)

x_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x.transpose((0, 2, 3, 1)), dtype=tf.float32)
x_torch = torch.Tensor(x)
x_torch = F.pad(x_torch, padding, "constant", 0)

# TF Conv2D
tf_conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(x_tf,
                         weights_tf,
                         strides=[1, stride, stride, 1],
                         padding="SAME")

# PyTorch Conv2D
torch_conv2d = F.conv2d(x_torch, weights_torch, padding=0, stride=stride)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tf_result = sess.run(tf_conv2d)

diff = np.mean(np.abs(tf_result.transpose((0, 3, 1, 2)) - torch_conv2d.detach().numpy()))
print('Mean of Abs Diff: {0}'.format(diff))
```

The output is:

```
Mean of Abs Diff: 2.2477470551507395e-08
```

I wasn't quite sure why this was happening when I started writing this question, but a bit of reading clarified this very quickly. I hope this example can help others.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I would like to use a [library](https://github.com/insilicomedicine/fcd_torch/blob/master/fcd_torch/torch_layers.py#L42-L53) that used your code above. Asking for compliance reasons – would you agree to license your code under MIT? (And if so, under what name?)