# Different outputs between torch and tensorflow conv2d according to stride parameter

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I made a simple convolution network on Pytorch and Tensorflow.

I copied weight to Tensorflow layer from pretrained layer on Pytorch, and there was significant different according to `stride` parameter

If the `stride` is set to 1, the l2 norm between the outputs is approximately same (0.8435), but when the `stride` is set to 2 or higher, the l2 norm is significantly high (156.6889).

Can anyone explain the why the computation of `stride` is different on Pytorch and Tensorflow?

```
# implementation on Pytorch
nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1, bias=False)

# implementation on Tensorflow
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", use_bias=False)

-> this results almost same output.

# implementation on Pytorch
nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2, bias=False)

# implementation on Tensorflow
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False)

-> this results different output.
```

Comment: different how? numerical values, or shape?

Answer (score 1):

There are some known differences between stride conv2d result of PyTorch and Tensorflow. In short, these are potentially slightly different implementation of result of padding - boundary effects, weight initialization - precision, dilation and group convolutions, numerical precision and calculation related issues.

For example, stride 2 means 3px filter move which may result considerable output difference. Some more details previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975843/comparing-conv2d-with-padding-between-tensorflow-and-pytorch):

Comment: Actually, the same output can be made by setting up the "tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=1)" and padding="vaild". Thank you for your help!